# Vue.js bad practice to reference store directly in v-for in template?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm working on my first Vue.js application (Vue 2.x) and I'm attempting to sprint before I can crawl, so it's been a trip.  I finally have the start of a working prototype, but am concerned I may trip myself up down the line with this. I have two sibling components under the root on the same page, like so:

```
<Root>
    <TimeCreate> router-view
    <TimeIndex> = $vm0 router-view
```

In TimeCreate I'm creating a record that I want instantly displayed within TimeIndex without a page reload of course.  TimeCreate creates the record and then I reload the times store using a dispatched action. In TimeIndex, I was defining a times variable in data like so:

```
 data: function () {
        return {
            times: this.$store.state.userTimes,
            ...
```

and then in my template:

```
<tr v-for="tm, index in times">
   ...
</tr>
```

but the TimeIndex component never "reacted" to the data change in store, because I had no watcher?  And then I read some SO posts about how it was bad to "watch" Vuex stores... but then when I changed my TimeIndex template for loop to this:

```
<tr v-for="tm, index in this.$store.state.userTimes">
   ...
</tr>
```

suddenly I have a de-facto store-watcher in my TimeIndex template, and it is working great, so far.

Have I set myself up for problems later with this approach?  I've been doing this sort of thing fairly frequently (putting store variables directly into a template) and I wonder if I'm going to pay later.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Has my answered helped you at all?

Comment: @li x Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so to address your concerns,

1)

```
data: function () {
        return {
            times: this.$store.state.userTimes,
            ...
```

Here your assigning the value of `this.$store.state.userTimes` at the point when this address is read to a new variable, it's just the value and unless it is a reactive type then it'll not receive any updates. It's unlikely you'll want to do this unless your positive that you want you want a copy of the value in an initial state and won't want to receive updates.

2)

```
<tr v-for="tm, index in this.$store.state.userTimes">
   ...
</tr>
```

As your using the value that is stored within Vuex by a reference to it you'll recieve updates whenever it's value changes by a mutation. You don't need to use a computed property as your just looking to use the value and aren't building logic into what to do with your component when the value changes. It's useful to note that your not actually watching the variable here, you simply just have a reference to the value contained within the store, no magic going on here.

3)

> Have I set myself up for problems later with this approach? I've been
>   doing this sort of thing fairly frequently (putting store variables
>   directly into a template) and I wonder if I'm going to pay later.
>   Thanks for your help

Your using state in the correct manner by asking the store for the current state and using a reference within your components logic, this is the correct approach to take for simple operations and largely for most content in a basic application.